# Stop Past Express JS or React Builds from Running

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, serve

I have been developing an app from the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) starting project.

Today I have been doing the following on my local machine:

1. deploying my react app using react-scripts start
2. deploying my react app by using react-scripts build then either serving the build by either...
3. (A) using the [npm module serve][] as follows serve -p 4001
4. (B) or attempting to server using a express app like follows:

Express app:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(4001);
```

I've just restarted my computer and it's still serving the site at:
http://localhost:4001/ and I cannot figure out how to stop it.

I wouldn't mind the continuous deployment of this server but when I build the project again. The changes are not reflected.

The only work around I've come up with is to now deploy at port 4025 and use the Express method coded above.

How the hell can I get rid of this weird residual app that continues to run (via some react process) at port 4001?

I'd really like that port back for sake of keeping it the same across different machines :(

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Hey sBanda, I am using OS X but turns out it was happening inside the chrome app. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that chrome keeps react apps running even if the server stops providing them.

Go to [chrome://serviceworker-internals](http://chrome://serviceworker-internals) and unregister them.